# New to React Hook, Why is state undefined after use once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question regarding how state is declared in react hook.

```
 const [ state, setState ] = useState({
        date: new Date(),
    })

 const { date } = state;
```

vs

```
const [ date, setDate ] = useState(new Date());
```

when date is called inside return, say

```
 return (
  <div>
    {date}
  </div>
)
```

console.log returns the current date, then undefined for the initial declaration, while the latter, the state persists.

Aren't these declarations the same? Why does the initial state persist only once?

Comment: As far as I know, those two should be the same. Can you include a bit more code? Do you touch the state anywhere else?

Comment: Did you just return the date? without getting any error? There should be an error because you can not render the date object.

Comment: I cant't seem to replicate the conditions for why the first way failed initially. You guys are right, they are the same. Thank you for the inputs

Comment: whan you do `const { date } = state;` you can not change 'date' till the component rerender and then the initial state will also change.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement `const [ date, setDate ] = useState(new Date());` 
date = current date, so you can access it as {date}

In the statement `const [ state, setState ] = useState({
        date: new Date(),
    })`
state is an object with key value pairs as date and new Date() respectively. Hence you need to use {state.date} in order to access date.

PLease accept this as answer, if you this helps you out.

Comment: This answer is pretty valid and works perfectly fine. Those who down voted this answer please write what is wrong with this answer. Please do comment when this answer was down voted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about the question you told since this is kind of unexpected behaviour. I have added some code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-play-ground-eqvin).

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const WithStateObject = () => {
    const [state] = useState({ date: new Date() });
    return <div>{state.date.toString()}</div>;
}

const WithStateAttr = () => {
    const [date] = useState(new Date());
    return <div>{date.toString()}</div>;
}

const App = () => {
    return <div>
        <div>With State Object <WithStateObject /></div>
        <div>With State attribute <WithStateAttr /></div>

        <h2>Second Time</h2>

        <div>With State Object <WithStateObject /></div>
        <div>With State attribute <WithStateAttr /></div>
     </div>;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can check your code with this one. I have added the same component two time just to explain there is no connection between each component.